# How to add a preloader

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, preloader

First post here.

I have a xml video background and need to add a preloader before the video is buffering. The problem is that I am loading the video from xml file and from what I've tried the preloader works for the swf file but not for f4v video loaded externally.

Any thoughts? You can check the preview here: http://www.freeportbiblecenter.org

What I've come with is to compress the video so Ill get a smaller file or change the buffer time, but the priority is to come out with the preloader.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do getBytesLoaded it would not matter what type of a file it is, flash would only check how many bytes are loaded and what was the total of it. So you can pause your video untill bytes loaded are equal to total bytes :)